# SQL query to create view for RDLC report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc, sql-server-data-tools

I've got a report in this format

[image: report format in two sections-Objectives measures feeds from the Objective table while the job role competencies feeds from the competence table]

The columns in the Objectives table to be passed to the report are

```
ObjectiveID, GoalDescription, Objective, Measure, Expectation, Comment
```

against the

```
S/N, Departmental Objective/Initiative, Employee Tasks, Performance Measure, 
Performance Expectation,  Comments
```

columns respectively.

Below is the data for the Objective table:

[image: Data for Objective table]

For the job role competencies section, the columns are

```
CompetenceID, CompetenceAreaDetailsDescription, CompetenceAreaDetailsExpectation
```

against the

```
S/N, Behaviours/Skills/Expectation, Expectations
```

columns respectively.

Below is the data for the Competence table:

[image: data for Competence table]

The total number of records in the `Objective` table is 9. It is a one-to-many column i.e an appraisee can have many objectives. The total number of records in the `Competence` table is 13, also a one-to-many table i.e an appraisee can have many competencies.

The only matching data in both tables is `AppraiseeId`.

My question: how can I create a view to join this two tables so as to serve as a datasource for the report.

To further illustrate, I want to display the 6 records from the `Objective` table where `AppraiseeId = 6` in the "Objectives, Task, Measures and targets" section since it has 6 objectives assigned to him and display only the 3 competencies assigned to him/her in the job role competencies section from the competence table.

I've written and rewritten quite a number of queries  but it only resulted in  many duplicated records.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].PlanningReport
AS
    SELECT
        "SpecificObjective"."ObjectiveId" "ObjectiveID",
        "SpecificObjective"."AppraiseeId" "AppraiseeID",
        "SpecificObjective"."Objective" "Objective",
        "SpecificObjective"."Expectation" "Expectation",
        "SpecificObjective"."Measure" "Measure",
        "SpecificObjective"."Comment" "Comment",
        "Competence"."CompetenceAreaDetailsDescription",
        "CompetenceAreaDetailsDescription",
        "Competence"."CompetenceAreaDetailsExpectation",
        "CompetenceAreaDetailsExpectation",
        "Competence"."ID" "CompetenceID",
        "Competence"."AppraiseeId" "CompetenceAppraiseId",
    FROM
        "dbo"."SpecificObjective" "SpecificObjective"
    LEFT JOIN 
        "dbo"."Employees" "Appraisee" ON "SpecificObjective"."AppraiseeId" = "Appraisee"."UserId"
    INNER JOIN
        "dbo"."Competence" "Competence" ON "SpecificObjective".AppraiseeId = "Competence".AppraiseeId
GO
```

I'm stuck. Kindly advice on what to do.

Comment: Please don't provide images of data. If you are going to provide sample data, do so as `text`, and even better, also provide `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't join "SpecificObjective" to "Competence" if I were you.
If "AppraiseeId" is the only common field between them?
Then it's a Many-To-Many relationship, and the resulting cartesian join effect isn't that usefull.

It's probably better to just create 2 views.
Because the 2 sections in the report seem separated.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwUserSpecificObjectives] AS
SELECT
 obj.ObjectiveId AS ObjectiveID
,obj.AppraiseeId AS AppraiseeID
,obj.Objective
,obj.Expectation
,obj.Measure
,obj.Comment
FROM dbo.SpecificObjective AS obj;
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwUserCompetences] AS
SELECT
 comp.CompetenceAreaDetailsDescription
,comp.CompetenceAreaDetailsExpectation
,comp.ID AS CompetenceID
,comp.AppraiseeId AS CompetenceAppraiseId
FROM dbo.Competence AS comp;
GO
```

If only one table/view datasource is supported in your tool, then that wouldn't help much.
But if your tool can get data out of XML then maybe you could select the Objectives and Competences as XML.

You can test it on *db<>fiddle* [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f5514e3744d0107eae18c856866476b1)

**Example:**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PlanningReport]
AS
SELECT 
 emp.ID AS EmpID,
 emp.FullName AS EmpFullName,
 (
       SELECT
         obj.ObjectiveId AS "@ID",
         obj.Objective AS "Objective",
         obj.Expectation AS "Expectation",
         obj.Measure AS "Measure",
         obj.Comment AS "Comment"
        FROM dbo.SpecificObjective AS obj
        WHERE obj.AppraiseeId = emp.ID
        FOR XML PATH('Objective'), ROOT('Objectives'), TYPE
 ) AS Objectives,
 (
        SELECT
        comp.ID AS "@ID",
        comp.CompetenceAreaDetailsDescription,
        comp.CompetenceAreaDetailsExpectation
        FROM dbo.Competence AS comp
        WHERE comp.AppraiseeId = emp.ID
        FOR XML PATH('Competence'), ROOT('Competences'), TYPE
 ) AS Competences
FROM dbo.Employee emp;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually using a RAD tool called Codeontime and it only supports one dataset to be embedded in the report hence my reason for combining the two tables. Any other advice please?

Comment: If that Codeontime tool is able to get data out of XML then maybe by selecting the objectives and competences as an XML type, per UserId.  Or use UNION like in Jen Tadros solution.

Comment: @hopeforall Not sure if that Codeontime tool can do anything with it, but I've added an example that gets those objectives and competences as XML.

Comment: Thanks i'll work with the suggested solutions and revert. Appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

I would do a UNION something like the following. You can then filter the view on AppraiseeId, and choose the columns you need for each section of the report differentiated by RowTypeId.

```
CREATE Report_View

AS

Select 

ObjectiveId, 
AppraiseeId,
1 AS RowTypeId,
Description, 
Objective,
Expectation,
Measure,
Comment

FROM Objective


UNION ALL

SELECT
NULL AS ObjectiveId,
AppraiseeId,
2 AS RowTypeId,
CompetenceAreaDetailsDescription AS Description
NULL AS Objective
CompetenceAreaDetailsExpectation AS Expectation
NULL AS Measure
NULL AS Comment

FROM Competence
```

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I've been able to do a union this time on three tables. Now working on filtering the data. Will keep you update. Thanks a bunch. Appreciate!

Comment: Jen! I've been able to get it to work as desired. Thank you